# DAX FILTER function with multiple criteria

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2014, dax

I have a DAX statement I run inside SSMS.

my original statement is:

```
evaluate(filter('rptLoan', [RemainingDays] <= 10))
```

and it works fine. I want to add another criteria as below

```
evaluate(filter('rptLoan', [RemainingDays] <= 10 and [CloseDt] <> "2017-01-31"))
```

but it is not working and I get below error

> Query (1, 47) Operator or expression 'AND' is not supported in this
> context.

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's simple. You can not use AND. You need to use && instead.

You also need to convert the string date to date type using `DATEVALUE` function

```
evaluate(filter('rptLoan', [RemainingDays] <= 10 && [CloseDt] <> datevalue("2017-01-31")))
```